# Flutter Master Data load

Tags: flutter, master-data-management

Flutter App : What is the best place to preload the Master Data?
My Query is with regards to preloading cretain Master Data - like list of URLs etc which dont change very frequesntly. I would like to load them once a day. Data is stored in Google Sheets.

Loading it in main function as asyn method preLoadData

```
void main() {
    preLoadData();
    runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to load it on splash screen, because in your case it will postpone app launch.

Comment: True that. Its does.